# Python for-loop syntax

Tags: python, for-loop, syntax, pythonanywhere

```
    for i in range(2, job_count+1):
        job_count_array['//form[@id='SubAvailSelectForm']/font/table[2]/tbody/tr[%d]/td[1]/small' % i] = sel.get_text("//form[@id='SubAvailSelectForm']/font/table[2]/tbody/tr[%d]/td[1]/small" % i)
```

I am getting a syntax error with the value side of this dictionary entry. Let me know what looks wrong to you. The interpreter is pointing to the `% i)`. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the syntax highlighting. You can’t just put a plain ol’ `'` in your `'`-delimited string.

Escape them as `\'`, or change your quotes to be consistent with the second string:

```
for i in range(2, job_count+1):
    job_count_array["//form[@id='SubAvailSelectForm']/font/table[2]/tbody/tr[%d]/td[1]/small" % i] = sel.get_text("//form[@id='SubAvailSelectForm']/font/table[2]/tbody/tr[%d]/td[1]/small" % i)
```

Comment: Thanks, such an easy fix! Amateur mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here:

```
job_count_array['//form[@id='SubAvailSelectForm']/font/table[2]/tbody/tr[%d]/td[1]/small' % i]...
```

do `"//form..."` instead of `'//form...'`: double quotes instead of single. As in your string you have `'SubAvailSelectForm'`, which is quoted with single quotes. So either make your string double-quoted, or escape single quotes in your string: `'\''`

Answer (score 0):

You have single quotes inside single quotes. The interpreter is confused :)

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your input!